# SQL Bitwise Masking

Tags: sql, sqlite, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitmask

I have a table that store access privileges as a bitwise mask:

- `0` none
- `1` user
- `2` super-user

I want to query, for instance, all accounts that have `user` + `super-user` priviledges, I thought that:

```
SELECT * FROM "accounts" WHERE "privileges" & 3;
```

Would work, but it's also returning all normal user (`1`) accounts. I can see that this it's correct because:

```
  1    (01)
& 3    (11)
-----------
= 1    (01)
```

I remember that this was easily doable in MySQL for instance, but I forgot how in the meantime.

I think the solution is probably a simple one, can anyone give me a hint on this?

Comment: I think you need to test whether the result of `"privileges" & 3` is actually equal to 3.

Comment: @MichaelLiu: Ah yes! Silly, silly me... That was it (although it won't work with `0`), thanks for the help and feel free to post your comment as a answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check whether the result of `"privileges" & 3` is actually equal to 3:

```
SELECT * FROM "accounts" WHERE ("privileges" & 3) == 3;
```

Otherwise, the query will select records where *at least one* bit is set.